# Why does rbind change one value when appending to a data frame?

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, rbind

I am working with vectors of datetimes and time zones.  A few of the time zones were recorded incorrectly and I want to adjust the times to fit the correct time zone.  I want to output a data frame.  It appears that when appending lines to the output data frame, rbind changes the value of one of the variables in one of the observations. Here is the an example code and the output showing the problem.

```
toy_problem <- function(){
  require("tidyverse")
   
  DateTime  <- c("2001-04-06 01:20:00",   # Input dates and times
                 "2001-04-05 19:20:00",
                 "2001-04-05 16:00:00",
                 "2001-04-06 01:15:00")
  listZones <- c("America/Chicago",       # Input time zones
                  "America/Chicago",
                  "America/Chicago",
                  "America/Chicago")
  trueZones  <- c("America/Detroit",      # Correct time zones
                  "America/Detroit",
                  "America/Chicago",
                  "America/Detroit")
  
  # Create an empty data frame
  
  outFrame   <- data.frame(inTime=NULL, outTime=NULL)
  
  for (i in 1:4) {                                        # Loop through the observations
   tReg        <- ymd_hms(DateTime[i], tz=listZones[i])   # Iinput date/time to POSIXct
   localTime   <- with_tz(tReg,tzone=trueZones[i])        # Fix the time to fit the correct TZ
   print(tReg)                                            # Starting date/time
   print(localTime)                                       # Adusted date/time adjusted
   
   # Put the observation into a one-line data frame
   
   thisFrame   <- data.frame(inTime=tReg, outTime=localTime)
   print(str(thisFrame))                                  # Check the one-line data frame
   outFrame    <- rbind(outFrame,thisFrame)               # Append to the ouput frame
  }
  print(outFrame)                                         # Print the output data frame
}
```

Here is the annotated output:

```
[1] "2001-04-06 01:20:00 CDT"
[1] "2001-04-06 02:20:00 EDT"                             # Correct
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:                   # Looks good
 $ inTime : POSIXct, format: "2001-04-06 01:20:00"
 $ outTime: POSIXct, format: "2001-04-06 02:20:00"
NULL
[1] "2001-04-05 19:20:00 CDT"                             
[1] "2001-04-05 20:20:00 EDT"                             # Correct
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:                   # Looks good
 $ inTime : POSIXct, format: "2001-04-05 19:20:00"
 $ outTime: POSIXct, format: "2001-04-05 20:20:00"
NULL
[1] "2001-04-05 16:00:00 CDT"                      
[1] "2001-04-05 16:00:00 CDT"                             # Correct!!!!
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:                   # Looks good!!!
 $ inTime : POSIXct, format: "2001-04-05 16:00:00"
 $ outTime: POSIXct, format: "2001-04-05 16:00:00"
NULL
[1] "2001-04-06 01:15:00 CDT"
[1] "2001-04-06 02:15:00 EDT"                             # Correct
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:                   # Looks good
 $ inTime : POSIXct, format: "2001-04-06 01:15:00"
 $ outTime: POSIXct, format: "2001-04-06 02:15:00"
NULL
               inTime             outTime
1 2001-04-06 01:20:00 2001-04-06 02:20:00                 # Correct
2 2001-04-05 19:20:00 2001-04-05 20:20:00                 # Correct
3 2001-04-05 16:00:00 2001-04-05 17:00:00                 # WRONG!!!!!!
4 2001-04-06 01:15:00 2001-04-06 02:15:00                 # Correct
```

I don't understand why that one value is being changed when it is appended to the output data frame.

Comment: rbind will coerce classes so it is possible that rbind sees the first timezone and uses that for all the rest.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  That certainly makes sense.  I can test that by reordering my example cases. If I put the America/Chicago time zone observation first, then if this is what is happening, all the following ones will be incorrect.  Do you know if the coercion can be overridden?

Comment: Yup.  Just did the experiment and you're right.  Now to find a fix...

Comment: I don't think it can be overwritten with `rbind` but I would try `bind_rows()` from dplyr

Comment: one solution is to have another column to specify how many hours difference the correct time zone is and then you can subtract that from the datetime to get the correct one.

Comment: Thanks again, Mike.  bind_rows() didn't work.  The real problem is a little more complicated because I determine the "true" time zone from the latitude/longitude of the sampling stations.  That routine returns Olson names and  I was hoping to avoid using the differences between the time zones because there are several Olson zones in the dataset.  I don't know of a function that will provide the hour difference between (say) "America/Chicago" and "America/Detroit".  I'll keep playing with it but the idea of using with_tz() simplified things considerably.

Comment: makes sense I would say then instead of storing in a data.frame store the information in a list so there won't be that coercion

Answer (score 0):

Mike's comment was correct.  rbind coerces classes so the class of the first entry was carried forward to all the others.  The reason that one entry was changed because its class differed from the first one put into the output data frame.

Comment: From `help("DateTimeClasses")`: "Using `c` on "POSIXlt" objects converts them to the current time zone, and on "POSIXct" objects drops "tzone" attributes if they are not all the same." Coerce the POSIX datetimes to the same timezone before rbinding.

Comment: Thanks, Roland.  I solved my problem by simply converting the times to character before using rbind to add them to the data frame.  I appreciate your help.